# UHF RFID reader ability to recognize tags in less than 1 m reading distance

Tags: rfid, vhf, hf

If the UHF RFID reader basic reading distance is up to 5 m, if adjusted to be less than 1 m or to be up to 1 m, can it be able to recognize all the tags? Or since it's for mid range reading, the reading distance should not be set to this short reading distance?

What factors that tags in this range effected by, so some can't be read after adjusting the range to be 1 m or less?

Answer (score 1):

Because an RF reader can read tags at 5m is doesn't mean it can do so for a passive tag. I'm saying this because the reader specification may be referring to an active tag i.e. one that contains a battery and is able to wake up when it detects the smallest "proximity field" from the reader.

So, once you've got that firmed up, adjusting the range to 1m (and this is usually done by lowering the "proximity field"), may give variable results - some may work outside 1m and some may not work until well-inside the 1m range.

I'm assuming your question is "What factors should be considered when reading a tag at a certain distance".

A tag relies on a wake-up field (or proximity field) to activate it and, the detected level of this field will vary from tag to tag - it's worse for passive tags because they are energy harvesting the field in order to create enough internal supply voltage for them to transmit a response and therefore there are more factors that can vary when energy harvesting.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Andy. My question was because I has been told " or uhf,the reading distance is too long, hard to control the range.The reading distance of UHF is effected by lots of factors. If adjust not more than 1 meter, under certain situation, some of the tag will be unable to be read."

Comment: For that I was asking about the possibility of recognizing all the tags in the range of 1 m while the basic range before re-setting it is up to 5 m. I need to know is there a difference in the performance between a UHF reader with reading distance up to 50 cm, and one with range up to 5 m but it’s adjusted to be up to 1 m (what's needed now for my testing is between 50 cm and 1 m). While there would be some tags near to the reader by just 20 cm.. can those be read by the reader, or there is a minimum distance the position of the tags should not be less than it to be read well?

Comment: There isn't usually a minimum distance to RFID readers.

Comment: Thank you @pjc50 , but I'm wondering why some vendors of RFID readers stated in specifications of some types of the readers (when they have long reading distance) they can't read well the tags that are near to them (less than 1 m far) ?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about ISO 18000-6, UHF passive RFID standard, reducing the distance may be achieved by reducing the output power of the reader and/or using a different antenna with less gain and/or different polarity. Even if you reduce the reading range, it does not mean that all of the tags should be detected.

However, there are a few configurations that may increase the possibility of detecting all tags. First of all Q Value must be selected according to the tag population. This increases the inventory time but reduces the possibility of interference between tags. Also, selecting a lower bit-rate and Miller-8 encoding should help to reduce communication errors.

These are general configurations that you can do, but it is hard to say anything more unless doing extensive testing with your specific setup.

Comment: Thank you @obareey , that helped me, but I still need to know if there is any effect of the short distance between the tag and the reader when the reader can read up to 10 m, for example, and why does that affect, if does so ?

Comment: Well, I had done several tests with readers with ranges more than 10 meters and sometimes we just stick the tag to the antenna. I don't remember a time when the tags are not read. As long as you need to detect the tag at least one time it shouldn't be a problem.